# Where does the static information for the application go in Android

Tags: android, design-guidelines

According to [Android Design Guideline](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html)! , the static information shouldn't be included in settings. So where should I put up all these information like about me,terms and conditions,version etc.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is within your [link](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html) in the text in the first image.

> If it's static information about the app (e.g. version number, terms
>   of service), organize it within a Help screen.

Comment: is the help screen just another activity? Do you have any links on tutorial for writing help?

Comment: the Help screen is a new Screen like the settings Screen, but only showing information with no options to click on. This can be implemented as a new `Activity` or as a `Fragment` as Fragments should replace additional Activities.